# Is a POST generated by a response to a Facebook app request guaranteed to be a signed request?

Tags: facebook, signed, apprequests

All,

I want to verify that when a user responds to an app. request generated via the Facebook Requests Dialog, that a signed request is sent to my application as part of Facebook's redirect to my canvas URL.

Thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is always be `signed_request`, but the the data it contain may differ for authorized users and users visited your app for a first time.

The `signed_request` itself will not contain any data related to request. And for sure it will not contain user details for new user...

You can save the response of callback passed to `FB.ui` for `Requests Dialog` which contain id of request and users involved. Once user accepts request (sent by application user), you'll get `request_ids` url argument passed to your application canvas url no matter if user is already accepted application or he is first time visitor. So you can just match the passed request id with stored data (you should be aware that single request can be sent to many users, so this method doesn't ensure the actual user you interact with, but all users involved in request).

Comment: Will it always contain which user is involved regardless of whether or not they've visited the app. for the first time?

Comment: Thanks Juicy - I'm aware of all of that. That's my problem, my current implementation for handling users that respond to the app. request requires that I know which user responded to the request, and as you said this doesn't appear to be possible.

Currently, we have a screen that shows up _before_ we send the accepting user on to the FB authorization, and at that point we need to know which user is responding to the app request.